# Bootstrap column height larger than defined

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to do a DIV-box with a height of 60px with bootstrap.

```
    <div class="container" >
      <div id="TopRow"class="row">
        <div id="TopDiv" class="col-sx12"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Then I assign a height to either TopRow or TopCol:

```
#TopRow{
height:60px;
box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

I expect to get a row container of 60px. The correct Value is shown for the element, however chrome shows me a height around 80px.

[image]

I did not find a ruler feature in IE 11 to check if it is a Browser issue.

Maybe you experienced anything similar?

This is the full code that is giving me the output in the picture. The ruler shows a heigt of about 80px

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Bootstrap Top Box</title>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">


<style>
#TopRow{
height:60px;
max-height:60px;
box-sizing: border-box;
}</style>


</head>
<body>
    <div class="container" >
        <div id="TopRow"class="row">
            <div id="TopDiv" class="col-sx12"></div>
        </div>
    </div>     

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/jvgb0bhm/)** (problem doesn't occur)

Comment: Demo fiddle added. Chrome reports `.row` at 60px. Must be your content.

Comment: did you check the ruler? is it saying the same as the marked container?

Comment: I don't use a ruler. I simply hover on an element while using the inspector. 60px. The container element doesn't have overflow set, so it collapses to zero height.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found the cause of displaying a different height than set in css:
If you zoom your page (even in another window at another time) the developer window will remember and zoom you page to the last used value! No hint shown whatsoever....

Answer (score 0):

add `max-height`

```
#TopRow{
height:60px;
max-height:60px;
box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

Comment: @Delcon post the full fiddle then